# How to write sub-query in Hyperledger Composer query?

Tags: sql, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to write a complex query in Hyperledger Composer base on this SQL code. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1
 WHERE value IN (SELECT column-name
                   FROM table-name2 
                  WHERE condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer Query language does not support any **sub-query**. I recommend you to follow this tutorial.

1. [query tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries)
2. [example of Query](https://www.blogsaays.com/blockchain-queries-hyperledger-composer/)